# Sorting by 2 substrings in a string in Java

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I am trying to order a list of strings (in Java) in reverse order based on 2 components of the strings, the first is the month (which needs to be ordered in reverse chronological order) and the second is the integer value at the start of the string (which does not represent the day hence it may exceed 31). For example:

`List<String> dates = List.of("13 Dec", "44 Jun", "12 Dec", "103 Aug", "22 Sep", "23 Sep");`

Once ordered should return:

`[13 Dec, 12 Dec, 23 Sep, 22 Sep, 103 Aug, 44 June]`

Can anyone show me an example of how this can be done? Thanks

Comment: The comparator could (1) split the strings (2) test if the second substrings are the same (3) if they are the same, compare the days and if not compare the month names using an array with the month names or similar.

Comment: How would I compare the month names using another array?

Comment: Are the months always 3 letters or can they be full month names?

Comment: If you have an array with all month short forms, you could use a linear search to finf the indizes and compare those.

Comment: The months are always 3 letters.

Comment: How can I incorporate the array with month short forms into the following:

```list.sort(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.split(" ")[1]).thenComparing(e->e.split(" ")[0]); ```

I am aware that this currently sorts the months alphabetically rather than reverse chronologically and that's what I am trying to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

1. split the strings

```
String[] split=string.split(" ");
```

2. test if the second substrings are the same

```
split1[1].equals(split2[1])
```

3. if they are the same, compare the days

```
Integer.parseInt(split1[0])<Integer.parseInt(split2[0]);
```

If not, compare the month names using an array with the month names or similar.

```
private static final String[] MONTHS={"Jan","Feb",...};
private int getMonthNumeric(String abbr){
    for(int i=0;i<MONTHS.length();i++){
        if(abbr.equals(MONTHS[i]){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
//in your comparator
getMonthNumeric(split1[1])<getMonthNumeric(split1[1])
```

A simple comparator (ignoring edge cases) could look like this (using a lambda):

```java
(a,b)->{
    String[] split1=a.split(" ");
    String[] split2=b.split(" ");
    if(split1[1].equals(split2[1])){
        return Integer.parseInt(split1[0])-Integer.parseInt(split2[0]);
    }else{
        return getMonthNumeric(split1[1])-getMonthNumeric(split1[1]);
    }
}
```

Your code sorting the list could look like the following:

```java
private static final String[] MONTHS={"Jan","Feb",...};
private int getMonthNumeric(String abbr){
    for(int i=0;i<MONTHS.length();i++){
        if(abbr.equals(MONTHS[i]){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
//Where you want to sort the date:
Collections.sort(dates,(a,b)->{
        String[] split1=a.split(" ");
        String[] split2=b.split(" ");
        if(split1[1].equals(split2[1])){
            return Integer.parseInt(split1[0])-Integer.parseInt(split2[0]);
        }else{
            return getMonthNumeric(split1[1])-getMonthNumeric(split1[1]);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach.  It uses some of the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) features to get the value for the month.

```
List<String> dates = new ArrayList<>(List.of("13 Dec",
        "44 June", "12 Dec", "103 Aug", "22 Sep", "23 Sep"));
```

First, get the integral month equivalent using the DateTimeFormatter. This avoids creating an external data structure to hold the months.

```
Function<String, Integer> monNum = month -> DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("MMM").parse(month)
        .get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR);
```

Then construct a comparator to compare the strings, first by month, then by number, both in reverse order.

```
Comparator<String> comp =
    Comparator.comparing((String str) -> str.split("\\s+"),
        Comparator.comparingInt((String[] a) -> monNum.apply(a[1]))
            .thenComparing(a -> Integer.parseInt(a[0])))
         .reversed();
        
dates.sort(comp);
System.out.println(dates);
```

Prints

```
[13 Dec, 12 Dec, 23 Sep, 22 Sep, 103 Aug, 44 June]
```

Comment: Why are you only reversing the months, but not the days?

Comment: And when you use the `java.time` API, you can let it do the entire job: `DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseLenient().appendPattern("d MMM").toFormatter(Locale.US); 
 dates.sort(Comparator.comparing((String s) -> f.parse(s), Comparator.comparingLong((TemporalAccessor a) -> a.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)) .thenComparing(a -> a.getLong(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH))) .reversed());`

Comment: @Holger First, nice second comment.  Didn't consider that since the values are not days of the month.  As for the order of the sort. The OP said *the first is the month (which needs to be ordered in reverse chronological order) and the second is the integer value at the start of the string (which does not represent the day hence it may exceed 31).*  Which I took to be an exclusive requirement to reverse the month.  Even when I looked at the desired output, I glossed over it.  But there was a reason to my madness.

Comment: After taking a closer look at your comment, I found what I was originally looking for.  A way to only split the String once and then use that in the subsequent compares.  So I updated my answer to reflect that.  I learned several things by answering this question.  A definite win on my part.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Provide your own Comparator to a #sorted stream method.
The example below compares month indexes. If they're equal (difference is 0), then the number is compared.
Check the [doc about sorted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-).

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

    /* [Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec, ] */
    static String[] shortMonths = new DateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths();
    static int getMonthIndex(String word) {
        return Arrays.asList(shortMonths).indexOf(word.substring(0, Math.min(word.length(), 3)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> dates = Arrays.asList("13 Dec", "44 June", "12 Dec", "103 Aug", "22 Sep", "23 Sep");

        dates = dates.stream().sorted((s1, s2) -> {
            String[] a1 = s1.split(" ");
            String[] a2 = s2.split(" ");
            int comp = getMonthIndex(a2[1]) - (getMonthIndex(a1[1]));
            return comp != 0 ? comp : a2[0].compareTo(a1[0]);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(dates);
    }

}
```

Will produce `[13 Dec, 12 Dec, 23 Sep, 22 Sep, 103 Aug, 44 June]`.